Error occurred during initialization of boot layer IntelliJ
Currently trying to create a GUI and run JavaFX but I got this error message:
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Time.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

I'm fairly new to intelliJ so I'm not quite sure what to fix. Thank you!
I've downloaded JavaFX and rebuild the project, tried creating a whole new one and nothing has worked.

Start here -> https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

See also the idea new JavaFX project wizard.

Note this error is not specific to JavaFX or IntelliJ. In Java, classes are contained within packages, and (since Java 9) packages are contained within modules. When a class has no package then it is in the "unnamed package". Named modules do not allow classes to be in the unnamed package. So, either move your class into a package or make your code non-modular.
